# command line syntax to launch visual studio and run a python script in it

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, command-line

Help

I have an excel file that I use to run different tools.  One of them is a plotting tool.  I am updating my plot tool to python, and I am planning to use Visual Studio to edit/run/debug my python plot packages.  But I would like to run them both from my excel visual basic.

So I think I am looking for a command line syntax (say that would work in a cygwin window) to launch visual studio, and load/run the python plot script.  When the python script is complete I want to be in the visual studio environment still (not close) so that I can review what it did, and edit/interrogate the plots, or iterate on the python script for the next try at making the plot.

Hope this makes sense, I was unable to find how to launch both visual studio, and python within it.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: why do you need VSC to run a python script, just execute `python  myscript.py` from the correct directory if needed

Comment: i want to be able to view the script and edit it and if when I manually do that I use vscode then I would like to use the same environment when I do it in automated fashion, if that is possible.